# SQLAlchemy aliases not aliasing?

Tags: python, sql, database, sqlalchemy

I have the following sqlalchemy code:

```
x = bbc.alias().c
w = bbc.alias().c
select([func.distinct(x.region)]).where(
    select([func.sum(w.population)]).where((w.region == x.region)) > 100000000
)
```

I would expect it to produce this SQL:

```
SELECT DISTINCT(x.region)
FROM bbc x
WHERE 100000000 < (
    SELECT SUM(w.population)
    from bbc w
    WHERE w.region = x.region
)
```

but instead it gives me this:

```
SELECT distinct(bbc_1.region) AS distinct_1 
FROM bbc AS bbc_1 
WHERE 1
```

Somehow the WHERE clause is collapsing, but for the life of me I can't see why. Am I doing something wrong with the aliases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as mentioned on the mailing list, a `select()` construct is a `FromClause` until you call `as_scalar()` on it, turning it into a `ColumnElement` suitable for SQL expressions:

```
x = bbc.alias().c
w = bbc.alias().c
select([func.distinct(x.region)]).where(
    select([func.sum(w.population)]).where(w.region == x.region).as_scalar() > 100000000
)
```